# use of だって in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> それだけじゃない、ほかの星座の神話**だって**有名なものだったらロマンチックに語ることができる。

what does だって do here? Something along the lines of the following ?

ほかの星座の神話**という**有名なもの

ほかの星座の神話**の**有名なもの

Answer (score 2):

だって=でも "even"

A little more context would help, but this looks as though it means "Not only that, [but] even myths relating to other constellations, if they are famous ones, can be told as romantic tales".

Comment: the speaker is adding on , after talking about one of the stories he knows. I didn't think it as ても as that would make だったら seem really redundant.

Comment: I imagine the speaker has been talking about particular legends relating to constellations - maybe the herd-boy and the weaving girl in Japan - and how they can be told as romantic tales and then goes on to suggest that other such legends could be treated in the same way, but with the proviso (which seems to occur to him as he speaks) that they would need to be well-known legends. Would that fit the overall narrative of the text you're reading?